# how to develop android app with asp c#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I am totally new to android app developement. I know C# somehow from the past and want to see is there really any tool to develop android base apps with asp.net.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET is for writing *web* applications. You can certainly write web applications which work well on mobile devices, but that's very different from writing applications to be *installed* on mobile devices.

You can write Android apps in C# using [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), although that's a commercial product. You may well find it simpler to get started using Java though, as that's what the vast majority of tutorials and examples will use.

Comment: oh what a pity, I found some xml android app developement tutorials in youtube which is started from this video http://youtu.be/SUOWNXGRc6g but I expected microsoft to develope some thing like a plug in tool for this matter. Thanks anyway

Comment: @HosseinDolatabadi: Why would you expect Microsoft to develop a plug-in for a phone platform which competes with their own? (As I say, there *is* Mono for Android...)

Answer (score 3):

Try phonegap. You can design cross platform applications for android, iOS, Windows mobile and other platforms. Its open source and they have tutorial on their website.

http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1):

Is vary easy with mono for android

just check : [http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Gallery](http://%3a%20http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Gallery)

Answer (score 0):

there is no tool, sdk, framework or solution that would let you do easily.  However, you're lucky C# is so similar to Java and you can learn it quickly by learning Java.  Believe me its easy.

You can also have a look at NDK (Native Development Kit) to have a C based development kit on android. Check this
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) allows you to write in C# for various platforms, including Android.
This will not be with asp.NET, though, but simple C#.